# Rails Params: require key, then permit array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Can someone help me figure out how to require and permit a set of parameters that looks like this:

```
<ActionController::Parameters { 
    "people"=>[
      {"id"=>"1", "first"=>"Jane", "last"=>"Doe"},
      {"id"=>"2", "first"=>"John", "last"=>"Doe"}
    ]
} permitted: false>
```

The data is being prepared in Javascript with this:

```
const formData = new FormData()
people.forEach(person => {
    formData.append('people[][id]', person.id)
    formData.append('people[][first]', person.first)
    formData.append('people[][last]', person.last)
})
```

I've tried some different formats (is there a more Railsish way to structure that?), and lots of different inputs to permit with no luck. My current attempt is

```
params.require(:people).each { |person| person.permit(:id, :first, :last) }
```

This doesn't crash, but also doesn't seem actually permit anything.

I've also tried setting up my data with `people[][person][id]` so I could do

```
params.require(:people).permit(person: [:id, :first, :last])
```

but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
params.require(:people)
params.permit(people: [:id, :first, :last])
```

The first line is just to raise an error if the key is missing. `.permit(people: [:id, :first, :last])` permits the people key and an array of hashes with the keys `:id, :first, :last`.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem but needed to allow other top level keys in the parameters as well (i.e. in this example `{ people: [{...}, {...}], token: '...' }`).

In the end I found this worked:

```rb
params.require(:people).map do |p| 
  p.permit(:id, :first, :last)
end
```

Just be aware that this returns an array, not a hash, so the original structure is flattened a little. Just in case this is useful for others searching like I was.